# Can't apply css styles to Administrate gem UI views to make responsive

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, responsive-design, rubygems

I'm trying out the Administrate gem in a Rails 4 app. It seems to work well and I like the clean UI. However, I need a responsive UI to allow the admin operations on mobile devices. I've looked everywhere in my project for possible css files which I could possibly modify but can't find anything related to the Administrate views.

Searching in browser developer tools reveals this css file path:
I can see a link to a stylesheet in the html head section pointing to this path:

```
/assets/administrate/application.self-c72e7c1a6aca7d4e9ae8ec6fdd92a87e81881a0012158db0cf618e4f2012d26f.css?body=1
```

I am not exactly sure what is going on here. The administrate folder does not appear to exist anywhere in the project. I checked `app/assets` and `lib/assets`. I thought the css styles might be being applied inline when the page is rendered but again didn't find anything in the UI's elements apart from classes`(eg. class="sidebar")`. The [Administrate documentation](https://github.com/thoughtbot/administrate) doesn't contain anything about customizing the interface either. It does say the gem's source code lives in the `app` and `lib` directories, but as I mentioned I can't find anything in either.

Maybe the css is being compiled by some hidden pre-processing on the fly? 
I understand that messing with the UI might not be recommended and could break the UI unexpectedly. All the same I'd like to give it a try.If anyone has had any luck customizing it for responsiveness I'd be grateful for any pointers to get started. Maybe there is something I am missing that can be tweaked in the Administrate settings. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you haven't solved this already, check out https://github.com/thoughtbot/administrate/pull/326.

Running `rails generate administrate:assets` will copy all of Administrate's assets into your application, which you can then customise however you like. You can also selectively copy only images, javascripts or stylesheets.